# What is the complexity of search in sorted std::list?

Tags: c++, search, std

What is the complexity of search in sorted std::list? I knew that complexity of search in sorted data is O(log n) if the data structure has random access. But since list doesn't have random access, what is it's complexity when it is sorted?

Comment: @dyp complexity of search by value

Comment: Note that independently of the search complexity, (linked) lists should be avoided unless you know they perform better than vectors / arrays in your particular case (and these cases are very rare). Interesting talk of the C++ inventor Bjarne Stroustrup about that topic: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YQs6IC-vgmo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, it's O(N). Search is always O(N) in a `std::list`, sorted or not.

Sorted collections help because you can know if you're too far, or not enough. But since you can't start anywhere but at one end of a list, it won't help.

Comment: thank u for ur repy.That means binary search doesn't help even if std::list is sorted?

Comment: Yes. Once you're in the middle of the list, you know if you should go left or right... but you already took O(N) time to get there by following the links.

Comment: list is double linked  list, it has two pointers in each node pointing pre/next. even if you know the node is in the middle, you still have to go through each next pointer to get to mid. However, if you use vector, it has random memory access, you can just jump to the middle node.

Comment: @user3852441 Well, it kinda helps still, as KerrekSB explains in his answer. But it doesn't help to reduce the complexity. Searching in  sorted vs unsorted lists are both linear time, but the first is faster than the latter, usually still a lot.

Answer (score 1):

It depends how you search. Given `std::list<T> x` and a value `v` that is not in the list,

- `std::find(x.begin(), x.end(), value)` is a linear search, so it will take `x.size()` comparisons and iteration steps, and
- `std::binary_search(x.begin(), x.end())` performs binary search with O(log(`x.size()`)) comparisons, but it will still have to increment iterators linearly to address the target of each comparison (and same for `std::lower_bound` etc.). The behaviour is undefined for this invocation if the list is not in sorted order.

Generally, iterator incrementing has a non-trivial cost for node-based containers, since it involves pointer chasing and is non-local in memory. However, you need to consider the cost of your value type's comparison operation (which could be high, e.g. for very long, almost equal strings). Moreover, you may be able to address memory locality by allocating nodes from a dedicated arena.

Comment: "It depends how you search" -- No. You even explain in your answer why it is linear time in every case...

Comment: @leemes: As I'm trying to explain in my answer, "it" is a little complex.

Comment: He asked for complexity, and it is a simple answer: O(n). What you explain is the *cost*, not the *complexity*. Of course, the explanation is still very helpful.

Comment: @leemes: Complexity isn't magic. It's measuring *something*. What is interesting to measure can differ. The OP is arguably under-specifying this.

Comment: Well, I guess since he doesn't ask for something specific we can safely assume he only wants a complexity dependent on the size `n` and assume every sub-operation to have a constant complexity. An overly precise expression would be: `T_search = T_advance * n + T_compare * log(n)`, and if you know the Ts, you can compute the complexity better. (Maybe comparison scans the whole list itself, so you have O(n log n))

Comment: @leemes: Yes, but complexity of *what*: Comparisons? (That's a reasonable assumption.) Iteration? (Many people don't even care about that.) Machine instructions? (Matters to some people.) Complexity of explaining to new team members? Etc etc. I'd rather not make assumptions and just explain each in turn.

Comment: Of the running time of course... And if you iterate n times, the complexity is never lower than O(n).