# is there any inbuilt function in c++ for linkedlist that works similiar to indexOf function provided by java?

Tags: c++, list, linked-list

I am using c++ inbuilt "list", I need to find an index of a value "target", in java there is a function `indexOf` that solves this problem, is there anything similar in c++?

I tried using `std::find()` but it returns the "target" value itself instead of the index? but I need index of the target value.

question: I am given an array of target values, and a list, traverse target array and for every element find its index in list and print index and then remove target value from list and push it at front

```
target values [3,1,2,1] , list : 1->2->3->4->5

for i=0 target[0] = 3 , index in list = 2 <- print it

updated list  3->1->2->4->5

for i=1 target[1] = 1, index in list = 1 <- print it

updated list : 1->3->2->4->5
```

and so on

Comment: `std::distance(myList.begin(), std::find(myList.begin(), myList.end(), value))` with 2 passes...

Comment: Indexes in `std::list` are rarely useful BTW, (for `std::vector` it makes sense, and previous comment is still valid, but `std::distance` doesn't need extra pass :) )

Comment: The "default" container should almost always be `std::vector`. And with a `std::vector` indexes makes sense, with a linked list it doesn't.

Comment: And please [edit] your question to tell us what the original problem you try to solve is. Why do you need to get an "index" into a list? Right now this is really to much of an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info).

Comment: i need target value index and store it and then i need to delete target value and insert it in front so i am using list bcz i can use push front function @Jarod42

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude question says to output target value index and then remove it and insert target value at front

Comment: that can be done with iterator directly, no need to use index. (in addition, if you repeat the process interleaved, iterator would be correct, whereas index won't)

Comment: The question state that you "need index of the target value", but it doesn't say *why* you need that. What the *original* problem is. Always please ask about the actual problem you need to solve, and then tell us what you have tried (preferably using a [mcve]) and how it didn't work. Please take some time to refresh [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: its a coding question , what do you mean why you need it

Comment: i have added example in question @Someprogrammerdude

Answer (score 1, accepted):

std::list doesn't have random access iterators. What you're looking for is likely the iterator to the object.

E.g.,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    list<int> l{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    for (auto i: {3, 1, 2, 1})
    {
        auto it = l.begin();
        for (auto index = 1; it != l.end(); it++, index++)
        {
            if (*it == i)
            {
                cout << "\n" << i << " is located at node " << index << endl;
                l.splice(l.begin(), l, it);
                cout << "Updated list: ";
                for (auto i: l) { cout << i << " "; }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: i need to print index of iterator , is it possible from your code?

Comment: Updated to reflect your question update, print now included. Lists have nodes instead of indices, so it prints the node beginning at node 1 (as opposed to index 0).

Comment: we are doing simple linear search here, can we do any better?

Comment: List searches are always O(N), because the iterators can only increment forward and backwards. [See this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26170743/what-is-the-complexity-of-search-in-sorted-stdlist)

Answer (score 0):

i did linear search on linkedlist for finding target,is their anyway to improve it in terms of time complexity?

```
list<int> ll;
int target,x=0;
for (it = ll.begin(); it != ll.end(); it++)
{

    if ((*it) == target)
    {
        break;
    }
    x++;
}
cout<<"found "<<target<<" at index"<<x<<endl;
```